# What should the logo look like?

Tags: discussion, content, design

The Raspberry Pi logo is trademarked by the foundation, so when deciding a logo we should be careful to respect their IP.

Also, what design elements and theme could make this site stand out?

What should site and logo look like?

**Trademark Rules**

There are a few posts expressing hope that the foundation will allow usage of their trademark.  It's fairly safe to say they will not, based on their reaction to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange and their [trademark rules](http://www.raspberrypi.org/trademark-rules).

> 1. When can I use the Raspberry Pi Logo?
>
> You may only use the Raspberry Pi Logo in connection with the sale or distribution of genuine Raspberry Pi products or services.
>
> If you use the Raspberry Pi Logo in this way on a website, the logo must link to our website at http://raspberrypi.org.
>
> 1. When can’t I use the Raspberry Pi Marks?
>
> You may not:
>
> (i)           use the Raspberry Pi Marks as part of your company name, company logo or product name

Comment: Just a question, but what is the markdown for that grey block you've used? (I can't edit the question to find out)

Comment: I just used > at the start of every line (indented the same amount on each line)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that.

Answer (score 14):

Why not ask the foundation for permission to use elements of the RPi logo? It's very distinctive and if we build a community of a high enough quality, then they might be happy for the co-promotion.

Comment: I agree. We should get them on-side rather than cause friction.

Comment: They mentioned that they weren't for creating a SO community for the Pi. So I doubt they will be on board.

Comment: They don't have to be "on board" as such, but it would be rude not consult them on these matters, whether they want to get involved or not. A community can get together and build a site (indeed many Pi related sites already exist) which has nothing to do with the foundation. IMO the community will flourish whether the foundation is involved or not. This site augments the existing forum, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: I agree it's worth asking, even if they say no (which could well be likely.)

Comment: @popey: They _would_ have to be on-board. The Pi logo is copyright, and SE copyrights their own logos. Legal issues.

Answer (score 4):

A slice of stylized raspberry pie (the dessert) perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some designs from [Ronan Forman](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/756/ronan-forman) of [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

[image: Pi logos!]

---

**Even More!**

[image: More Pi logos!]

---

## Thanks Ronan Forman!

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be nice if **the theme** (not the logo) related to the look of the board of the Pi.

[image]
Maybe stylized like this, or maybe some other way, but I think it would be good if **the theme** included the board's look.

Comment: This is a little bit too complex to be a logo.

Comment: @Bryan, yeah, it's meant to be for the overall theme, not the logo. I'll clear it up.

Comment: I really like this.

Answer (score 2):

What about a graduated Raspberry-colored version of the striped question mark logo:

[image: Stack Exchange Sprites]

Or this one:

[image: Stack Overflow Logo]

But instead of bars, have the drupes from the Raspberry coming out of the box

Obviously original logos in both cases which simply evoke the relationship with both Stack Exchange and Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I don't think making our brand a modification of SE's or SO's is a good idea. Besides, a completely new brand is much more fun!

Comment: @TomMedley I wasn't advocating a modification.  I was advocating a new brand which evokes the feelings of both of the other original brands.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use the RPi Raspberry from the original logo as the dot on the `i` in `Raspberry Pi`?

Answer (score -1):

If the foundation do not allow their logo to be used (though I hope they do) I would go for a line-art picture of a RasPi PCB.